# Как подключить Circle (Крипто обменник) к IOS/Android приложению (Просто идеи)?

Tags: javascript, python, android, ios, blockchain

Всем привет хотела узнать как можно подключить Circle(circle.com) к Android/IOS приложении. Даже идей нет как это сделать. Можете поделиться идеями как можно это реализовать :)

Comment: начните с [изучения api](https://developers.circle.com/docs/introducing-circle-apis) и [углубляйтесь потихоньку](https://developers.circle.com/docs/circle-payments-api-quickstart)

Comment: Хорошооооо спасибо))